# Weird JS Alert on Wordpress Site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, alert, elementor

This is my first question after reading so many topics before. I just ran into an issue with a weird JavaScript Alert on a `Wordpress` site I adjusted for a client.

I work with `Elementor` and there are several plugins installed on the site. I initially recognized some weird behaviour of the `Elementor` editor not loading at times. After Creating some headers and a footer the site began to throw an alert `"height = 500"` which I tried to debug.

It came down to 3 plugins which when deactivated, resolved the issue, but I am not able to deactivate them permanently as the client depends on them.

Maybe someone has seen this issue before and could lead me in the right direction. I am thankful for every input at this point. Or maybe you know how to best debug the problem by finding the source of the alert?

The site is called https://sdaccounting.net

Comment: Welcome to SO Mirco. Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: View the page source and search for `alert`. You'll find `alert('height =' + art_h);` … in an inline script in the head. If you have the files on your local machine you could use a text editor like notepad++ to find the plugin (search in files) that holds that code or something related eg `client_tabordion`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome Mirco,

Your website includes the following block of code into the `<head>` tag

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var art_h = jQuery('.client_tabordion #section3 article').height();
    var art_h = art_h + 500;
    alert('height =' + art_h);
    jQuery('.client_tabordion').css('height', art_h);
    });
</script>
```

As you can see the alert is into the piece of code.

Comment: You are great guys, thanks so much! Could find out the source by searching for the css class. Turns out an other dev inserted the script into the header.php of the wordpress theme. I commented it out, issue resolved.